# make json string to match exact string for pie chart datasource?how to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

here is my recieved JSON string

```
    "{Date:'15/05/2015',y:'6'},
     {Date:'01/08/2015',y:'6'},
     {Date:'02/08/2015',y:'6'},
     {Date:'08/08/2015',y:'72'},
     {Date:'09/08/2015',y:'6'},"
```

i have to make it exactly like that for my datasource in pie chart

```
    var datas = [
                  {date:"02/02/2015",y:6},
                  {date:"15/05/2015",y:6},
                  {date:"01/08/2015",y:6},
                  {date:"02/08/2015",y:6}
                   ];
```

here is working js fiddle [js fiddle working for json](http://jsfiddle.net/dgroung302/a2zw5bhh/)

here is my c sharp code for making json

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair2 in dic)
        {
            int perce = pair2.Value;
            var perct = ((double)perce / total) * 100;
            int perc = Convert.ToInt32(perct);
            string datesval = pair2.Key;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("Date:'" + datesval + "',y:" + perc + "");
            string newq = sb.ToString();
            list.Add(newq);

        }


     StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string element in list)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m <= list.Count() - 1; m++)
            {
                sb2.Append("{" + list[m] + "},");
                line = sb2.ToString();

              }
            break;
        }
```

the string should be modified using javascript

> remove (") double quote from start of string and add [ . also remove (,") from end and add ]

also show error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on line
           $('#container').highcharts({

Comment: need to fix your link, helps to post all your code here as well. especially the working parts.

Comment: Have you looked at the various ajax examples? What's the actual question - how to make the ajax call? How to parse the data?

Comment: Generally you need to load data by $.getJSON() and parse data to correct format. I mean pair [name, value], where value is number like 40 not 40% string.

Comment: check changes now and answer

Comment: Looks like javascript syntax error or not loading all files properly.

Comment: change _y_   **datatype** to _int_ instead of _string_ because it accept _y=6_ not _y='6'_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use string builder and eval , I am extentendinng the above from Line you built

```
         string c = line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(c);
      //  builder.Replace(",\"","]");
       // builder[0] = '[';
        TrimEnd(builder,',');
       // builder.AppendFormat("[\"{0}\"]", builder.ToString());

        string combine = "["+ builder.ToString();
        string newcom = combine + "]";
        return newcom;
   }
    static void TrimEnd(StringBuilder builder, char letter)
    {
        // ... If last char matches argument, reduce length by 1.

        if (builder.Length == 0)
        {
            string c = "sorry";
        }
        else if (builder[builder.Length - 1] == letter)
        {
            builder.Length -= 1;
        }

    }
```

in succes of ajax do this

```
    var v = eval(response.d);
```

now use this in pie chart

2nd error is because jquery files conflict with each other use jquery 1.9.1.js first  then graph files

Comment: Generally eval is not a proper solution. Better is build correct json or useJSON.parse().

Comment: convert _json string to json object_ simple